# Produce two columns of word combinations from one column of words where ID column values are equal

Tags: r, networkd3

I am trying to prepare a dataframe to feed into the `forceNetwork` function of [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3)

Here is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(Case.Number = c("127967", "127967", "127967", 
"127967", "141330", "141330", "141330", "141330", "141240", "141240", 
"141240"), Word = c("account", "want", "membership", "sort", 
"unhappi", "vr", "info", "miss", "csrf", "unhappi", "dissatisfi"
)), .Names = c("Case.Number", "Word"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

For the words of each case number, I want to produce a dataframe with two columns of all possible (and unique) two word combinations like below, without duplicate combinations (including reverse order) for the same column and without combinations of the same word

```
127967 account want
127967 account membership
127967 account sort
127967 want    membership
127967 want    sort
141330 unhappi vr
141330 unhappi info...

excluding
141330 unhappi unhappi
```

I have tried the following to get the combinations:

```
source <- c("remove")
target <- c("remove")
ID <- c("remove")
df <- data.frame(ID = c("remove"), source = c("remove"), target = c("remove"))

for(i in unique(tbl$Case.Number)){
  for (r in grep(i, tbl$Case.Number)) {
    if(r < max(grep(i, tbl$Case.Number))){
      ID <- i
      source <- tbl$Word[r]
      target <- tbl$Word[r+1]
      rbind(df, cbind(ID, source,target))
    }

  }

}

View(df)
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-joining and then filtering:

```
setkey(dd, Case.Number)
dd[dd, allow.cartesian = TRUE][Word < i.Word]
#     Case.Number       Word     i.Word
#  1:      127967    account       want
#  2:      127967 membership       want
#  3:      127967       sort       want
#  4:      127967    account membership
#  5:      127967    account       sort
#  6:      127967 membership       sort
#  7:      141240       csrf    unhappi
#  8:      141240 dissatisfi    unhappi
#  9:      141240       csrf dissatisfi
# 10:      141330       info    unhappi
# 11:      141330       miss    unhappi
# 12:      141330    unhappi         vr
# 13:      141330       info         vr
# 14:      141330       miss         vr
# 15:      141330       info       miss
```

Comment: Easy and does exactly what i'm after. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

using `tidyr::expand`...

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "
Case.Number Word
127967    account
127967       want
127967 membership
127967       sort
141330    unhappi
141330         vr
141330       info
141330       miss
141240       csrf
141240    unhappi
141240 dissatisfi
")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Case.Number) %>% 
  expand(Word, i.Word = Word) %>% 
  filter(Word < i.Word)
```

Here's a `tidyverse` way of doing it (less convoluted than the original below, leveraging @Gregor's brilliantly simplistic filtering method)...

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "
Case.Number Word
127967    account
127967       want
127967 membership
127967       sort
141330    unhappi
141330         vr
141330       info
141330       miss
141240       csrf
141240    unhappi
141240 dissatisfi
")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Case.Number) %>% 
  mutate(i.Word = Word) %>% 
  complete(Word, i.Word) %>% 
  filter(Word < i.Word)

# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups: Case.Number [3]
   Case.Number Word       i.Word    
         <int> <chr>      <chr>     
 1      127967 account    membership
 2      127967 account    sort      
 3      127967 account    want      
 4      127967 membership sort      
 5      127967 membership want      
 6      127967 sort       want      
 7      141240 csrf       dissatisfi
 8      141240 csrf       unhappi   
 9      141240 dissatisfi unhappi   
10      141330 info       miss      
11      141330 info       unhappi   
12      141330 info       vr        
13      141330 miss       unhappi   
14      141330 miss       vr        
15      141330 unhappi    vr
```

Here's a `tidyverse` way of doing it (if a bit convoluted)...

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "
Case.Number Word
127967    account
127967       want
127967 membership
127967       sort
141330    unhappi
141330         vr
141330       info
141330       miss
141240       csrf
141240    unhappi
141240 dissatisfi
")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

as_tibble(df) %>% 
  group_by(Case.Number) %>% 
  mutate(Word = list(as_data_frame(t(combn(unlist(Word), 2))))) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  unnest(Word)
```

It's a bit easier to understand if you run the following commands sequentially to see what they do. `combn` does the magic of expanding your vector into all possible combinations.

```
vec <- c("account", "want", "membership", "sort")
combn(vec, 2)
t(combn(vec, 2))
as_data_frame(t(combn(vec, 2)))
```